Example 5.2.6 in Weibel's Homological Algebra
Let $\{E^r_{pq}\}$ be a spectral sequence, such that $E^r_{pq}$ is zero unless $p,q\ge 0$. (I.e. it is bounded in the first quadrant).
Let's consider a term of the form $E^n_{0y}$; since the differential with domain $E^n_{0y}$ lands in a zero term, I'd say that $E^{n+1}_{0y}$ will be a quotient of $E^n_{0y}$ (modulo the image of the differential with codomain $E^n_{0y}$). Going on for a finite number of steps we arrive to say that $E^\infty_{0y}$ is a quotient of $E^n_{0y}$.
Similarly I'd say that any term of the form $E^n_{x0}$ is a subobject of $E^\infty_{x0}$. However in the example mentioned in the title, page 124 of the book, Weibel makes a similar argument (the same it seems to me) but gets to the opposite conclusion:  $E^\infty_{0y}$ is a subobject of $E^n_{0y}$ and vice versa. I'm sure that I'm using his same indexing with $p,q$ as the usual $x,y$ and I dont understand what did I do wrong. What do you think?

Your reasoning is correct, and Weibel's statement is wrong. I think your argument is convincing enough, but to make sure, there's a list of errata for the book, availabe here, which lists this exact error.

Thank you for the link, it's really helpful!
